# Website on phone is not the same on laptop mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

The website mobile version looks like this:[desktop mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjpLD.jpg)

But on my phone it looks like this: [phone view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II7A7.jpg)

I make use of box-sizing, still don’t know why it’s having different scaling

Comment: How about try to make a responsive using `media-query` on CSS ?

Comment: I used media-query, didn’t work. I’ve been having this problem for a while.

Comment: Okay. Did you used `%` instead of `px` or any exact number?  `%` will make element more flexible.

Comment: can you share codes?

Comment: You did _"used"_ media-query. Why not attach them to the question?

Comment: I’m new here, I don’t know how to share the code. But I used @media screen and (max-width:992px){ code here}

Comment: You need to post your code. You shouldn’t need media query for this, likely to be more how you are sizing things, eg relative to viewport, and whether you have set doctype etc.

Comment: This is the link to the code: https://codepen.io/mikemulla/pen/JjOzMmG

Comment: Could you put your code into your question, otherwise the question might get closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of the image in terms of the viewport size then you get a circle (at least on the tests I did on IOS).

Obviously you will want to set the vw amount to suit your particular requirement.

This snippet sets it to 10vw for this demo.

However, there is another factor. I think you are relying on the natural dimensions of the images to be square. If they aren't then things could look distorted so this snippet adds an `object-fit: cover.`This still relies on the faces being in a more or less central position in the overall image - but that would need correction depending on each individual image.

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .kill {
    background: #1d1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(4.9);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4.9);
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .navi {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .nipp {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 33;
  }
  
  .rate {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    margin-right: 25px;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .rell {
    justify-content: end;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .mage {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .mage1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .mage2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .mage4 {
    border: 3px solid #5cb85c;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .butn {
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
  }
  
  .txt {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .kill {
      background: #1d1d1d;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      backdrop-filter: blur(4.9);
      -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4.9);
      height: 100%;
      color: white;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .navi {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .nipp {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 33;
    }
    .rate {
      background: transparent;
      border: 0;
      outline: none;
      margin-right: 25px;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .rell {
      justify-content: end;
      display: flex;
    }
    .mage {
      width: 10vw;
      height: 10vw;
      object-fit: cover;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .mage1 {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .mage2 {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .mage4 {
      border: 3px solid #5cb85c;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .butn {
      border: 0;
      outline: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px;
    }
    .txt {
      margin-left: -10px;
    }
  }
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-ejwKkLla8gPP8t2u0eQyL0Q/4ItcnyveF505U0NIobD/SMsNyXrLti6CWaD0L52l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="kill">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark nipp navi">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <i class="bi bi-whatsapp h2"></i> Whatsapp
        </a>
        <div class="rell">
          <button class="rate text-light h2"> <i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
          <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle w-25">
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section>
      <div class="container pt-4">
        <div class="mage1">
          <div class="mage2">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/10.jpg" class="rounded-circle mage ms-3 " alt="">
            <h6 class="mt-2 txt">You</h6>
            <button class="butn"> <i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="mage2">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg" class="rounded-circle mage ms-3 mage4" alt="">
            <h6 class="mt-2 txt">David</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="mage2">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/6.jpg" class="rounded-circle mage ms-3 mage4" alt="">
            <h6 class="mt-2 txt">David</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="mage2">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/18.jpg" class="rounded-circle mage ms-3 mage4" alt="">
            <h6 class="mt-2 txt">David</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="mage2">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/14.jpg" class="rounded-circle mage ms-3 mage4" alt="">
            <h6 class="mt-2 txt">David</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>







  </div>




  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Incidentally, I'm not sure why you bother to repeat the styling und er the media query, for example for mage, but that doesn't affect your question so I've left it.

Comment: Bro, you did it! You’re a boss!